# Передача экземпляра случайного класса нескольким методам

Tags: c#, наследование

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с использованием экземпляров классов.
Есть класс Person и наследующиеся от него классы Tom, Ban, Pit, Jack (в них переопределяются отдельные поля и функции родительского класса, в том числе методы Name(), Age() и Epitaph()).
Программа должна выбирать случайным образом один из классов-наследников, после чего с этим наследником должны работать несколько функций.
Пример классов:

```
// Родитель
internal class Person
{
    public string Name()
    {
        int random_index = rand.Next(2);                        
        var name = new List<string>(2)
        {
            "Black",
            "White"
        };
        return ("Фамилия: " + name[random_index]);
    }
}

// Класс-наследник

internal class Tom : Person
{
public new string Name()
    {
        int random_index = rand.Next(2);                        
        var name = new List<string>(2)
        {
            "Daw",
            "Smith"
        };
        return ("Фамилия: " + name[random_index]);
    }
}
```

Случайный выбор реализован так:

```
private Person ChosenCase = GetRandomPerson();

private static Person GetRandomPerson()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int man_choice = rand.Next(1, 5);
                    
        switch (man_choice)
        {
            case 1:
                return new Tom();
            case 2:
                return new Ban();
            case 3:
                return new Pit();
            case 4:
                return new Jack();
        }

        return new Person();
    }
```

Функции реализуются так:

```
public void MakeButtons()
    {
        List<string> features = new List<string>(3)
        {
            "Имя",
            "Возраст",
            "Эпитафия"
        };

        foreach (var item in features)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = item;
            btn.Click += (x, args) => LifeResult(ChosenCase, item);  // при нажатии должно выводиться значение поля дочернего класса
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
    }

private void LifeResult(Person ChosenCase, string item)
    {
        Label newLabel = new Label();
        
        switch (item)
        {
            case "Имя":
                newLabel.Text = ChosenCase.Name();
                break;
            case "Возраст":
                newLabel.Text = ChosenCase.Age();
                break;
            case "Эпитафия":
                newLabel.Text = ChosenCase.Epitaph();
                break;
            default:
                newLabel.Text = "Вы задали непонятный вопрос!";
                break;
        }
        
        flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(newLabel);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что функции выводят значения полей и результаты работы методов родительского класса, а не наследников. Это происходит даже если заменить в методе случайного выбора return new Person() на return new Jack() (если совсем убрать эту строчку, среда разработки выдает ошибку «не все пути к коду возвращают значение»).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Вы не привели каким образом наследуются классы. Переопределяются ли методы Name, Age, Epitaph?

Comment: Дополнил: классы Tom, Ban, Pit и Jack наследуются от Person. Указанные в примере и некоторые другие методы (всего их порядка двухсот) переопределяются

Comment: ОК. Если методы Name, Age и Epitaph переопределяются, а после вызова GetRandomPerson() Вы устанавливаете необходимые свойства используя перегруженные методы, то у Вас какая-то ошибка в коде, которую (я по крайней мере) здесь не вижу. Может знающие люди подскажут. Как вариант, залейте Ваш код на какой-нибудь онлайн IDE хостинг (к примеру на [replit](https://replit.com/languages/csharp), который поддерживает компиляцию из нескольких файлов) и удалите не относящиеся к проблеме 100500 свойств и методов.

Comment: Покажите родительский и один из дочерних классов (все методы не надо, достаточно пары). Я практически уверен, что override не сделан.

Comment: Добавил пример классов

Comment: public **new** string Name() - так и оказалось. Перегрузки нет.

Comment: Спасибо,  с перегрузками методов еще не сталкивался (совсем недавно изучаю с#).
К сожалению, решить проблему не вышло. Если я правильно понял, override применим, если родительский класс абстрактный, то есть его методы только намечены, но не могут быть вызваны программой. В моем случае у родителя есть две сотни методов, из которых в наследниках переопределяется 30-50 (разный набор), но программа должна работать с полным набором свойств. Если в каждом наследнике придется прописывать все 200, теряется смысл ООП.

Comment: Простое удаление new в наследниках вызывает предупреждение системы, а выводится всё равно результат работы родительского метода :(

Comment: Пометьте ключевым словом `virtual` те методы базового класса, которые собираетесь переопределять в дочерних (с помощью ключевого слова `override`).

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО, Александр! Теперь всё работает отлично.